# Absent PHP extension: runtime exception or logic exception?

Tags: php, oop, exception, runtime, logic

In some point of my code, I must test if openssl extension is present. If not, should I throw a `RuntimeException` or `LogicException`? Wrong server setup falls in which of them?

Comment: Given those two options it would be a RuntimeException

Comment: Because is constitutes a shortcoming of your runtime environment ... might even want to make a more specific exception for that.

Comment: @Orangepill A long time has passed, but I could ask you to write an answer that I can mark as correct here?